# How to validate white space in jquery

Tags: jquery, trim

I have a textbox and I am trying to validate it in jquery. The condition is, it should not validate if user only types space bar. Currently it validates it, since the `length` is not equal to 0. How can I validate for empty white spaces?

```
var name = $('#txtName').val();
if (name.length <= 0) {
    $('#divName').css("border-color", "red");
    ShowHideById('sendEmailByCustomer', 'true');
    isValid = false;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $.trim() to remove whitespaces:

```
var name = $.trim($('#txtName').val());
if (name.length <= 0) {
    $('#divName').css("border-color", "red");
    ShowHideById('sendEmailByCustomer', 'true');
    isValid = false;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**$.trim()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string as shown :-

```
var name = $.trim($('#txtName').val());
if (name.length <= 0) {
    $('#divName').css("border-color", "red");
    ShowHideById('sendEmailByCustomer', 'true');
    isValid = false;
    return;
}
```